# Xgboost4j - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, xgboost

I am running the sample code here to train xgboost model :
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/xgboost4j_spark_tutorial.html

I have installed the below jar files to my cluster :
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ml.dmlc/xgboost4j-spark/0.90
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ml.dmlc/xgboost4j/0.90

I am getting an error
"Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class error" when calling Xgboost classifier.  which suggests some compatibility issue with scala version. Can anyone elaborate how to resolve this?

Comment: What version of Spark are you using ?

Comment: Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12

Answer (score 1):

You're using spark 3.x, that is compiled with Scala 2.12 with xgboost4j-spark 0.90, that is compiled with Scala 2.11

Scala 2.12 and Scala 2.11 compiled codes are not binary compatible, meaning it can't work together, raising that kind of issues.

You should either downgrade spark to version 2.4.x or upgrade xgboost4j-spark to version 1.2.0 or greater. You can get the list of version of xgboost4j-spark on [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ml.dmlc/xgboost4j-spark)